# HTTP client test integration into Jenkins

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing, jenkins, integration-testing, intellij

IntelliJ Ultimate offers a code editor to test HTTP request (including asserts). Those tests can even be stored as a file or run-config to be executed for later api testing.
The official documentation can be found here: [docu http client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html)

I am wondering now whether it is possible to integrate the execution of those api tests into jenkins, in order to execute those tests alongside with the unit tests as a part of quality assurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (yet). But there already is a feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42002